# Message success display time

Tags: magento-1.7

How can I set how long will the success message be displayed. Now its visible for one second and then it disappears. Can I somehow set that this message stays visible for 10 seconds? Or maybe, that it never goes away?

I tried with jQuery but that's not a good solution. Where in Magento is defined how long will the message be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably built in to your (custom) Template. The Default magento behaviour is that it stays on the page until a refresh.

- You could check the template settings, there might be a property which you can change
- You can inspect the javascript/jquery(?) code which makes the message disappear and change it. (if you post the url, I can look into it for you too)
- You can ask support where you got the template

Comment: You were right, its really JavaScript code, that sets the setTimeout for how long will the massage be displayed. Thank you so much for your help.